# What happens when a CSS style isn't supported by the browser, but the property is?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I'm wondering what happens if a CSS style is supplied for a property which the browser supports, but the style itself isn't supported.

Take for example the following in IE8;

```
background: url(../path/to/img.png);
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
```

Does IE8 simply ignore the second style due to it's lack of supported for CSS3 colours?

Thanks :).

Comment: Why don't you try yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Does IE8 simply ignore the second style due to it's lack of supported for CSS3 colours?*

The answer is **YES**, it will completely ignore that value, and hence it won't render any color, it's a common practice to use a fall back with a hex value like

```
.class_name {
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

So, when you write the `background` twice, it's completely valid, the browsers *who understand* the `rgba()` will render an opaque background, but the browsers *who don't understand* `rgba()` will use `#000`.

Though, there are various workarounds for that, like, you can use `:before` or `:after`, with `filter` property with a negative `z-index`, which can be used as an opaque background, or you can do is, use a normal 1x1 px opaque png image only for IE8.

For example

```
background: url("IMAGE_URL_HERE")\9; /* Targets IE8 and below */
```